# Free, simple video editor for a basic video overlay

Tags: windows, gratis, video, video-editing

I'm looking for something that is free and straightforward, that allows for a simple video overlay on another video in Windows 10. Here what I've tried:
-Lightworks: crashes, and when not, puts a watermark in the free version
-Filmora: watermark
-Movavi: watermark
-VirtualDub: not easy to use. I've spent already 2 hours downloading plugins and trying to figure out how to do the simplest thing.

So what I want is something like Movavi, but that doesn't put a watermark in the free version.

Answer (score 1):

[OpenShot](https://www.openshot.org/) is free, open source, and even has a [portable](https://portableapps.com/apps/music_video/openshot-portable) version (no registry or file clutter) if you prefer.

From the homepage:

> We designed OpenShot Video Editor to be an easy to use, quick to
>   learn, and surprisingly powerful video editor

According to the [features](https://www.openshot.org/features/) page, the software supports "Compositing, image overlays, watermarks".

From https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2194047

> You can overlay the two videos with OpenShot
>   Just make a new project. Import both
>   video files. Add the clips as two separate tracks (for example track 1
>   on bottom, track 2 on top). Change the layout of the top track to fill
>   only a fraction of the screen (for example 25%), and change the
>   position of the track (for example top left). Export the project as a
>   new video file.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to [download HitFilm Express](https://kubadownload.com/hitfilm-express-2019-download.1137.html). It is easy to use and offer all necessary options to edit video.